# UIButton placeholder text

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

The `FirstViewController` has a `UIButton` that needs its title set to the string "Pick your Favorite Food".

Once a user clicks that `UIButton`, they segue to `SecondViewController` that has a `TableView` list of different Food items.

When they select that `TableView cell` of Food, they pop back to the `FirstViewController`, where the `UIButton` title should say what Food they selected.

Right now, the `UIButton` just says `"(null)"` until a user selects a Food.  So I need it to say "Pick your Favorite Food" when they open the app until the point they've selected a Food, at which point the UIButton title will say which Food they selected.

Any thoughts?  I can add any snippets of code if needed, thanks!

EDIT:
Here is the code I already had for setting the title of UIButton-

```
[buttonOne setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", FoodOne] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

SOLVED:
I used the response @lnafziger gave me below, and it worked perfectly.  Thanks to everyone who tried to answer the problem I was having!

Comment: `[button setTitle:@"Pick your food" forState:UIControlStateNormal];`

Comment: @H2CO3 I'm already setting the button to the code I have in the question (I added code).  So I'm guessing I cant do `[buttonOne setTitle:@"Pick your food" forState:UIControlStateNormal];` also.  What do you suggest?

Comment: @H2CO3 Thankfully lnafziger quickly understood the problem and provided me a solution to my question.  See his answer below-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the code that you have now to:

```
// If FoodOne is a NSString, then you can skip this part and just use FoodOne
NSString *foodOneDescription = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", FoodOne]
if ([foodOneDescription length] == 0)
    [buttonOne setTitle:@"Pick your Favorite Food" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
else
    [buttonOne setTitle:foodOneDescription forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

This will set it to your "placeholder" text unless a food has been selected, in which case it will use the food's description (as in your example).

Comment: No problem, that's what we are here for!

Answer (score 1):

You could override `-viewWillAppear:` in your view controller subclass, and set the button's text there. That way every time your view gets show you can check and reconfigure the button. (I don't quite know where that data comes from, if its something like CoreData then you could also do fancier stuff like Key-Value Observing, or in the worst case implement your own change propagation system using NSNotifications).

Comment: This makes a lot of sense... I'm going to look into it.  Thanks so much for taking a careful look at my question and giving a meaninful & helpful response!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any "placeholder", you can set/change the title as many times as you want. Just set it to "Pick your Favorite Food" initially and set it again after an item has been picked.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I updated my question to make it clearer the code I already have for the title of the UIButton, how would I edit what I have to do what you're saying?